# NodeJS reusable HTTP requests using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have to make tons of API calls in my app. I have like 8 trillion Axios calls.

So I decided to make a helper function for axious and pass the URL to it every time I want to do HTTP Request   .

But I get an error here are my files:

apiUtils.js:

```
const axios = require("axios")
const handleError = require('./apiHandleError')
const SERVER_DOMAIN = process.env.HOST;
const AuthorizationHeader = process.env.AUTH
const getHeaders = () => {
    return {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': AuthorizationHeader
        },
    };
};
// HTTP GET Request - Returns Resolved or Rejected Promise
const getRequest = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(`${SERVER_DOMAIN}${url}`, getHeaders())
            .then(response => {
                resolve(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(handleError(error))
            });
    });
};
module.exports = getRequest

 //apihandleError.js - Common Error Handler Function
 const handleError = (error) => {
     let {
         status,
         message
     } = error.response;

     switch (status) {
         case 401:
             console.log(status)
             break;
             // do something when you're unauthenticated
         case 403:
             console.log(status)
             // do something when you're unauthorized to access a resource
             break;
         case 404:
             message = ({
                 status: `Couldn't reach Arena Gaming Server. Try again later`,
                 result: 404
             })
             // do something when the resource isnot found
             break;
         case 500:
             console.log(status)
             // do something when your server exploded
             break;
         default:
             // handle normal errors with some alert or whatever
     }
     return message; // I like to get my error message back
 }
 module.exports = handleError
```

And this is how I call the function:

```
const userId = getRequest(`/api/reports/users/${userId}/general`)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    // do something with User #5
  })
  .catch(errorMessage => {
    console.log(errorMessage);
    // the error has already been handled by handleError
    // the message get's passed here
    // do something like store it in redux, etc.
  });
```

I get errorMessage result is : `` status: `Couldn't reach Arena Gaming Server. Try again later`,
         result: 404 ``

Comment: what in the world....why wouldnt you just `return axios.get()` wrather than unwrapping and wrapping a promise to do the same thing?

Comment: also..verify your env vars are all set :)

Comment: I don't understand can you elaborate with an example, please ? :)

Comment: All env vars all good :D

Comment: so....axios.get returns a promise already, meaning you dont need to `return new Promise(resolve,reject){}`. you use the pattern you have in code above for "promisifying" a callback.

Comment: you want to deconstruct `error.response` in the handler....you only do `error`. See [this](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)

Comment: oh and duh....if you already "handled" your error in `handleError`, you would need to re-throw to catch it where you have a console.log :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to wrap the `axios.get` which already returns a promise in another promise. you could simplify this like this

```
const axios = require("axios");
const handleError = require("./apiHandleError");
const SERVER_DOMAIN = process.env.HOST;
const AuthorizationHeader = process.env.AUTH;
const getHeaders = () => {
  return {
    headers: {
      Authorization: AuthorizationHeader
    }
  };
};
// HTTP GET Request - Returns Resolved or Rejected Promise
const getRequest = async url => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${SERVER_DOMAIN}${url}`, getHeaders());
    return response;
  } catch (err) {
    return handleError(err);
  }
};
```

Usage can be as you are using or `async/await`

Hope this helps

Comment: it's good the problem is i want to specify messages on the error handler file to send back my code does that but your code doesn't let me do that i edieted my question for better explanation

Comment: @mohamedadel so...why did you mark this as the answer then?

Comment: When you mark a wrong answer correct, you mislead other people who may have the same issue you are having. Though you are being "nice" to Ashish, you arent doing the community any favors

Comment: I am not sure why it is misleading as the original question has been answered. the follow up problems is something which can be a separate question or discussion. so i don' think any one is being nice to me. There was a question and there is answer. Hope that clears your doubt